# Java WindowBuilder -> Export as .jar (Runnable or Applet)

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jar, executable

I installed the WindowBuilder Plugin for Eclipse 3.7.

I created a very simple GUI with various methods (JFrame, JPanel, Application etc.).  I tried to Export my Project as a runnable JAR / a .jar file.  I have to choose the Main Class: It does not show anything to select! The Export still works but the file is useless.

How do I export my GUI class properly?

EDIT: Seems I need a main method to make the class show up in the main class list. But the problem is, that WindowBuilder creates a class like this:

```
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;


public class myGuiClass extends JApplet {

    /**
     * Create the applet.
     */
    public myGuiClass() {
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JButton btnMybutton = new JButton("myButton");
        btnMybutton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                System.out.println("Button pressed!");
            }
        });
        btnMybutton.setBounds(10, 11, 91, 23);
        getContentPane().add(btnMybutton);

    }
}
```

If I create a main method here, I cannot create my JApplet, as it it not allowed to reference its non-static constructor in the static main method. At least I dont know how to do it. So how would I go about exporting this very simple one class program to a runnable .jar or an applet?

@Andrew: The "Application" meant one of the options in the WindowBuilder->Swing Designer menu. which is in fact called Application Window, and there are also JApplet, JFrame, JDialog and so on.
I would like to have something executable that I can bring to another PC or run via web, so I dont have to deal with crude executing things with the cmd window...

Comment: Does any class have a `public static main(String[] args)` method?  Also, what is an `Application`?  It is not part of the J2SE.  BTW - figure this out before considering an applet.  Applets are usually not a solution to a problem, but instead introduce more problems.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. In fact I tried it with just one class, and no it does not have a main method. It seems to need one to show up in the main class list, but there is a problem, I have edited the question above ->

Answer (score 3):

Try this, this is the way to create a jar or runnable jar in eclipse, all your external libraries in the project will be included

```
File -> Export-> Java ->Runnbale JAR file

Launch configuration : your Class containing the public static void main(String[] args)

Export destination : Target place

Library Handling:

Package required libraries into generated JAR

FINISH
```

Comment: `Package required libraries into generated JAR` Ahh..  'Fat Jar' (in principle, if not trade name).  Not very optimal for a [JWS](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) deployed application (which is becoming more common, even for embedded applets).

Answer (score 1):

Try this code - works as either applet or free floating (frame based) app.

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

/** This is an hybrid application/applet.  It can be run
 * as either a JFrame or JApplet. */
public class MyGuiApp extends JApplet {

    /** Construct the GUI for an applet. */
    public void init() {
        try {
            SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait( new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    GUI gui = new GUI();
                    getContentPane().add(gui.getGui());
                }
            });
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /** Launch the GUI in a frame. */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            @Override 
            public void run() {
                JFrame f = new JFrame("My GUI");
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                GUI gui = new GUI();
                f.getContentPane().add(gui.getGui());
                f.pack();
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}

class GUI {

    public JComponent getGui() {
        // Use layouts! ..
        JPanel p = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
        // ..possibly with borders.
        p.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10,10,10,10));

        JButton btnMybutton = new JButton("myButton");
        btnMybutton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                System.out.println("Button pressed!");
            }
        });
        p.add(btnMybutton);
        return p;
    }
}
```